# Onesignal Notification permission issue in android 13, No permission dialog box appears

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal, ionic-native, ionic6, android-13

No permission dialog box appears.Only able to fetch **getIds** ,Cannot able fetch **pushToken ** in android 13 device.By this notification is not able to fire.

Facing onesignal notification issue in android 13 devices. Notification is not fired in device because. I checked the log of fetching ids while **initialzing ** app in **app.component.ts**

it is something like this.

log of android 13 device (Notification completely not working ):
Here the permission is not enabled in app info.

```
getIds: {"userId":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","pushToken":""}
```

log of android 12 or lower device (Notification completely working ):
Here the permission is enabled in app info.

```
getIds: {"userId":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","pushToken":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

====package.json====

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/android-permissions": "^5.45.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/app-version": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation": "^5.44.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/google-analytics": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/keyboard": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/location-accuracy": "^5.45.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/native-geocoder": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/network": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/social-sharing": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/splash-screen": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/status-bar": "^6.2.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/system-alert-window-permission": "^6.2.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.4.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.14",
    "@ionic/cordova-builders": "^7.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "angular-cropperjs": "^1.0.2",
    "cropperjs": "^1.5.13",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sentry-cordova": "^1.0.4",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "com.razorpay.cordova": "^1.4.15",
    "cordova-android": "^10.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.14",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.9.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-system-alert-window-permission": "0.0.6",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.11.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "com.razorpay.cordova": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "18.0.2"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "sentry-cordova": {
        "SENTRY_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION": "6.4.1"
      },
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-system-alert-window-permission": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

====app.component.ts====

```
constructor(
    private menu: MenuController,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private platform: Platform,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private httpSignin: SigninService,
    private alertConfirm: ToastService,
    public globalVar: GlobalvariableService,
    public msg: MessageParserService,
    private storage: AppStorageService,
    public globalFun: GlobalFunctionService,
    public oneSignal: OnesignalService,
    private appVersion: AppVersion,
    private googleAnalytics: GoogleAnalytics,
    private iab: InAppBrowser,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
      this.oneSignal.OneSignalNotification()
    });
  }
```

=====onesignal.service.ts====

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertController, LoadingController, NavController, Platform, PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppStorageService } from './app-storage.service';
import { GlobalvariableService } from './globalvariable.service';
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OnesignalService {

  constructor(
    private oneSignal: OneSignal,
    private platform: Platform,
    private globalVar: GlobalvariableService,
    private loadingController: LoadingController,
    private storage: AppStorageService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
    public alrtCrtl: AlertController,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  async OneSignalNotification() {
    await this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        // Initialise plugin with OneSignal service
        //  await this.oneSignal.startInit(this.storage.OneSignalAppID, this.storage.SenderID);
        await this.oneSignal.startInit(this.globalVar.oneSignalAppId, this.globalVar.oneSignalSenderId);  
        // When a push notification is received handle
        // how the application will respond
        await this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe((msg) => {
          // Log data received from the push notification service
          console.log('Notification received');
          console.dir(msg);
        });
        this.OneSignalPlayerID();
        // When a push notification is opened by the user
        // handle how the application will respond
        await this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((msg) => {
          // Log data received from the push notification service
          console.log('Notification opened');
          let notification_obj = msg.notification.payload.additionalData;
          if (notification_obj) {
            if (this.globalVar.loginInfo != '') {
              this.fnOpenNotification(notification_obj);
            } else {
              this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('login');
            }
          }
          // console.dir(msg);
        });
        this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
        // End plugin initialisation
        this.oneSignal.endInit();
      } else {
        this.globalVar.playerId = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX';
      }
    });
  }

  async OneSignalPlayerID() {
    await this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        this.fnShowLoading();
        // Retrieve the OneSignal user id and the device token
        this.oneSignal.getIds().then((ids) => {
          console.log('getIds: ' + JSON.stringify(ids)); //UNABLE TO FETCH pushToken in android-13 
          // alert('getIds: ' + JSON.stringify(ids));
          // this.storage.deviceId = ids.userId;

          this.globalVar.playerId = ids.userId;
          this.storage.set('player_id', this.globalVar.playerId);
          this.fnhideLoading();
          return ids.userId;
        });
      } else {
        // this.fnhideLoading();
        this.globalVar.playerId = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX';
        this.storage.set('player_id', this.globalVar.playerId);
      }
    });
    // return this.globalVar.playerId;

  }

  async fnShowLoading() {
    await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please wait fetching configuration..',
      spinner: 'circles',
    }).then((ldr: any) => {
      ldr.present()
    });
  }

  async fnhideLoading() {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let topLoader = await this.loadingController.getTop();
      while (topLoader) {
        if (!(await topLoader.dismiss())) {
          await topLoader.dismiss();
          break;
        }
        topLoader = await this.loadingController.getTop();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

**Please help, Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You already did the [Add Notification Permission Prompt](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-13-push-notification-developer-update-guide#step-3-add-notification-permission-prompt) step?

If not, you can [show prompt with an in app message](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/how-to-prompt-for-push-permissions-with-an-in-app-message), or use the not recommended method `promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse()`.

Dont' forget to update your dependencies, you are using older versions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-cordova-plugin

Setup:

```js
import OneSignal from 'onesignal-cordova-plugin';

// Call this function when your app starts
function OneSignalInit(): void {
  // Uncomment to set OneSignal device logging to VERBOSE  
  // OneSignal.setLogLevel(6, 0);

  // NOTE: Update the setAppId value below with your OneSignal AppId.
  OneSignal.setAppId("YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID");
  OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler(function(jsonData) {
      console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  });

  // Prompts the user for notification permissions.
  //    * Since this shows a generic native prompt, we recommend instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission  to better communicate to your users what notifications they will get.
  OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse(function(accepted) {
      console.log("User accepted notifications: " + accepted);
  });
}
```

Setup documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk-setup#step-4-update-project-settings-to-target-android-13-android-only

Comment: latest version of onesignal is not working with android 10/13. shows "Plugin not installed" error you can check my question for more detail. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73485937/19843403

cordova android is allowing only API level 32 and one signal needs API level 33 docs : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/

I have tried promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse() but its not working it throws error. In my case notification permission is directly OFF in android 13 where else other version it is ON.
can you please help! @SidiBecker

Answer (score 0):

After OS 13 device must need notification permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```